# What was wrong with running princomp() in R?

Tags: r, infinite, pca

I was running PCA with princomp(). My dataset is called vt.

```
pca = princomp(as.matrix(vt))
Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only
```

However, when I check if I got infinite values, there's none.

```
sum(is.infinite(as.matrix(vt)))
[1] 0
```

What was wrong with my analysis?

vt is a data.frame with all numeric values.

```
is.numeric(as.matrix(vt))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about `vt`? Do you have missing values?

Comment: Have you checked whether you have NA's in your dataset? Those also give the same error message. So use `is.na()` instead of `is.infinite()` to check for these missing values.

Comment: Yes, I have missing values. I used na.action = na.omit, but it doesn't work. However, if I use na.omit(vt) as input, it's fine. Why na.action does not work?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would appear to be the removal of missing values. There are two ways to remove missing values from the data set. You can either remove them using `na.omit()` function explicitly before calling `princomp()` or you can use a formula interface to `princomp()` with an argument `na.action=na.omit`. You have used the matrix interface to `princomp()`, and `na.action` is not an option for the matrix interface, hence it does not work in your case. See ?princomp for more details.

Consider the following:

```
# Add one missing value to USArrests data set
USArrests[1,1]<-NA

# Does not work (matrix interface)
princomp(USArrests)
# Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only

# Does work (formula interface)
princomp(~., data=USArrests, na.action=na.omit)

# Does work (remove missing values before PCA)
princomp(na.omit(USArrests))
```

So in your case something like:

```
pca = princomp(~., data=as.matrix(vt), na.action=na.omit)
```

should do the trick.